# Android Hebrew EditText

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

Im working on hebrew logo quiz app and i need to use an edittext that the user type what he see and then compare it to the preset value.
The current code is

```
        Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String word = String.valueOf(test.getText());
            String word2 = String.valueOf("טקסט בעברית");
            if (word==word2){
                tv.setText("True");
            }
            else tv.setText("False");
        }

    });
```

and the output is always False as well as the correct answer..
I really need help here

Comment: Use String.equals() method instead ==

Comment: remember strings are arrays of chars not primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing two object by their references and because they are not same, returned value is always false. you should compare their values not their reference. read more [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/)

`String` class in java has a method for comparison. you should use `equals` method. read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm)